# Should I ask a poker game design question on Stack Overflow or Game Dev?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a long question, but the heart is this

> Can anyone give an example of a poker hand evaluator that has good style?

Which site is right for this question?

**EDIT:**
My question is about writing code. I want to make a simple poker hand evaluator. I've brainstormed some solutions, but they're not really workable. I have tentative framework code (e.g. what the Card class looks like), but nothing at the heart of the hand evaluator. I put this stuff in my full question. Is the real problem how I'm wording my main question?

Comment: Not so much any...well, at least not on SO. Style questions are hard to answer and "gimme the codez" is not better. Though, I made the experience that GameDev is rather...relaxed about those kind of questions, maybe you should ask on there Meta just to be sure...I don't mean crossposting, but rather waiting for an answer here first.

Comment: @UristMcBobby If not any, do you know of any non-SE sources I can ask? Or perhaps a way of editing my question so that I can ask it on one of the SE sites?

Comment: @Eva if you want programming example I would suggest you first try for yourself then post in Stack Overflow what you have tried, what you expect etc. If it's pure theory, Game Dev sounds a more fitting place.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I have brainstormed a few things, but I didn't write out code because they were too ugly to implement. Will that be ok for SO?

Comment: @Eva pretty much gray zone - quite a risk if you ask me but one that might be worth taking if you feel like you can clearly explain the problem and that it will benefit others.

Comment: Stack Overflow or Game Dev but not [poker.se]?

Comment: @mmyers I was under the impression Poker was for enthusiasts. I'm just writing some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to rethink "the heart" of your question. What *exactly* are you asking? If your question is specifically about the code behind a poker hand evaluator, then it belongs on Stack Overflow. On the other hand  <sub>(no pun intended)</sub>, if your question is about the game more generally, I would put it on Game Dev. For instance,

Good fit for Stack Overflow:

> I am writing a poker hand evaluator. So far, I've gotten {code, code, code}, but I can't get around {some issue} on {some line}. How can I {do this}?

Good fit for Game Dev:

> I am designing a poker game. I've looked at {some hand evaluator}, {other hand evaluator}, and {still other evaluators}. It looks to me like {benefits of one over the other}. Is this a correct assumption? What are the benefits of these different approaches?

Comment: Grr. ----------

Comment: +1, I like this answer for showing what *would be* a good question (for either site).

Comment: My question is closer to the SO version. I've brainstormed some solutions (which I put in my full question), but haven't written any code because the solutions weren't workable. (I explain why in my full question) I also have some tentative framework code (e.g. what the Card class looks like) that I put in my question. Is the real problem here how I'm wording my question?

Comment: To be clear, the biggest problem right now is that the question you've proposed would be swiftly closed as Not Constructive. The Stack Exchange system doesn't allow you to poll answerers with open-ended questions. If your question parallels my SO example, then start on the project, get some work done on it, and when you have a question about a specific problem, ask it. As casperOne said. the most valuable thing you can do in a question is show what you've tried. Dozens of questions get closed every day because the asker didn't do anything on their end before asking.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know that will be accepted on *any* Stack Exchange site.  It's not that the question is necessarily bad, but but *Stack Exchange* standards, we prefer questions that are answerable in a subjective way.

When you ask (emphasis mine):

> Can anyone **give an example** of a poker hand evaluator **that has good style**?

I've highlighted the two problems above.

The first ("give me an example") is very open ended in that you're asking people to *list* things that fit this criteria.  The Q&A format of Stack Exchange is really not very good at handling list items, for a number of reasons, and more often than not, these questions are closed as "Not Constructive".

The second ("that has good style") is again, "Not Constructive".  What defines good style?  Everyone has an opinion, and they don't always align with each other.  Granted, everyone's answer to *every* question is an opinion of sorts, but for most of the questions on Stack Exchange, the answers are *verifiable*, which allows them to be rated.

That said, the answer to your question of which site you should post on is * neither*, as the network isn't geared towards questions that have those specific qualities.

Comment: Is there a way I could reword/rework my question so that it does fit SE standards? Or do you know of another site I can post my question?

Comment: @Eva Are you looking to *write* a poker hand evaluator or are you looking for a library/program that already does?  If it's the latter, then there's not much you *can* do, as Stack Overflow doesn't really work for providing recommendations.

Comment: I want to write a poker hand evaluator. Not a professional library-type one that's optimized for speed, just one I can use in my tutorial.

Comment: @Eva If you are writing a poker hand evaluator, then I would start doing it, and then write a question about very specific issues you are having with the evaluator (perhaps an algorithm about how you are evaluating hands).  That said, the most important thing you can do is show *what you've tried*.  Also, while I think that a questions like these (which are about specific, answerable problems) are on topic on Stack Overflow, Game Dev would be the more appropriate site, as it's about, well, game development.